# VK code for comparing + and other SHIFT characters

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I am creating a calculator with a label to show what the user is entering from his keyboard.

The problem comes when the user presses the '+' button from keyboard, because '+' from keyboard is (Shift + '='). The KeyEvent's `getKeyChar()` and `getKeyCode()` methods interpret as two separate ASCIIs (one is 16 and other is 61)

The screenshot below shows the `getKeyCode()` output when Shift + '=' is pressed to generate a plus sign:

[image]

Comment: don't to use Keylistener for Swing JComponents (but be sure there is possible to determine possition on Keyboard, numpad, with modifier, etc, read Oracle tutorial for working code example) use KeyBindings instead

Answer (score 0):

this is something very similar to your doubt, hope this helps you out,

```
class DispatcherListener implements KeyEventDispatcher{
    private int level=0;

    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED){
            if(e.isControlDown() && e.isShiftDown()){
                if(this.level==0 && e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_S){
                    level++;
                }else if(this.level==1 && e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_H){
                    level++;
                }else if(this.level==2 && e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_O){
                    level++;
                }else if(this.level==3 && e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_W){
                    level=0;
                    this.showHiddenWindow((JFrame)SwingUtilities.getRoot(e.getComponent()));
                }else{
                    level=0;
                }

                //System.out.println( "level: " +  level );
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

and used it as this:

```
KeyboardFocusManager manager = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager();
manager.addKeyEventDispatcher( new DispatcherListener());
```

Comment: DispatcherListener  is merely a class name, please feel free to change name as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

Why not catching the typed character by testing the KEY_PAD event, so the '+' sign could come from the numeric pa, not only from the "Shift" and "+" combination ?

For example, something like:

```
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    int eventID = event.getID();
    if (eventID == KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED) {
      char key = event.getKeyChar();
      if (key == '+') {
         /// Continue here...
         System.out.println("++++");
      }
    }
}
```

-- Edit: Here is a complete example (simplified from http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Event/KeyEventDemo.htm)

If you try to type "Shift" + "+", the displayed character should be "+"

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class KeyEventTest extends JPanel implements KeyListener, ActionListener {
  JTextArea displayArea;

  JTextField typingArea;

  static final String newline = "\n";

  public KeyEventTest() {
    super(new BorderLayout());

    JButton button = new JButton("Clear");
    button.addActionListener(this);

    typingArea = new JTextField();
    typingArea.addKeyListener(this);

    displayArea = new JTextArea();
    displayArea.setEditable(false);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(displayArea);
    scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(375, 125));

    add(typingArea, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(button, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
  }

  /** Handle the key typed event from the text field. */
  public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    displayInfo(e, "KEY TYPED: ");
  }

  /** Handle the key pressed event from the text field. */
  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
  }

  /** Handle the key released event from the text field. */
  public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
  }

  /** Handle the button click. */
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    displayArea.setText("");
    typingArea.setText("");
    typingArea.requestFocusInWindow();
  }

  protected void displayInfo(KeyEvent e, String s) {
    String typedKey = null;
    int id = e.getID();
    if (id == KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED) {
      char c = e.getKeyChar();
      typedKey = "key character = '" + c + "'";
    } 
    displayArea.append(s + newline + "    " + typedKey + newline);
    displayArea.setCaretPosition(displayArea.getDocument().getLength());
  }

  /**
   * Create the GUI and show it. For thread safety, this method should be
   * invoked from the event-dispatching thread.
   */
  private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("KeyEventDemo");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JComponent newContentPane = new KeyEventTest();
    newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
    frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        createAndShowGUI();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Regards

Comment: it does not compare it with + sign ..because it shows ascii of shift and of equals to sign

i mean it reads shift and equal to seperatly rather than reading it as Shift + '='

Comment: strange: when i test it, i get the '+' sign when i compare. Are you testing that event.eventId value is KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED before calling the event.getKeyChar() method (and not KEY_PRESSED or KEY_RELEASED) ?